# Forum for Ubuntu Phone

Tags: discussion

Since Ubuntu phone gonna hit the market very soon, I was wondering if there's  gonna be separate forum for Ubuntu phone or AskUbuntu will do the job?

Comment: I think it is important to understand that askubuntu is not an internet-forum, but a Q&A site. This is a big difference, and although maybe not crucial to your question if a separate entity for Phone willb e coming, I think it is important to not this.

Answer (score 5):

The [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) states (as on-topic):

> Using and administering Ubuntu, including official Ubuntu derivatives.

I would consider the Ubuntu Phone to fall into one of those categories.  We [already support](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5308/44179) Ubuntu [on the Nexus 7](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7) and I don't see where Ubuntu Phone will be that different.

I also think the Ubuntu Phone will not be a big enough topic to create a new Stack Exchange site or forum about.

*However*, the FAQ also states (as off-topic):

> Issues with the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1) (More information about Alpha and Beta release issues).

So discussing this topic, e.g. hardware support, development, etc, would probably be considered off-topic right now.

Comment: *Issues* (which probably means *problems*) in Ubuntu Phone is off-topic right now. I'm not sure all questions relating to Ubuntu Phone are off-topic. Most are currently unanswerable (not constructive), but we probably won't be getting a lot of off-topic questions until real testing is happening.

Comment: issues = problems = bugs.

Comment: There are already questions about the Ubuntu phone, you can find them under the [tag:mobile] tag.