# Do we support 13.04 on the Nexus 7?

Tags: discussion, scope

Per the [Ubuntu Wiki Nexus 7 installation page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation):

> **Please note as of 12/7/2012 we strongly urge users to re-flash to Raring 13.04**

The wiki also points users with problems to ask questions here:

[image]

This is leading to an influx in 13.04 Nexus 7 installation questions (though we haven't had *too* many yet).

Do we support 13.04 when it's being installed on a Nexus 7? 
We might me able to if we have enough users tinkering with Ubuntu on a Nexus 7.

There was a conversation about this in chat a while back, but I can't find it now.

If we don't support 13.04 on the Nexus 7 we will need to clarify that.  Either in our [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) or the Ubuntu wiki.

Comment: Doesn't this fall into the category of "In Development OS" questions?

Comment: @TheLordofTime Yes it does.  So?

Comment: If that's the case, then wouldn't the decision of [this meta thread](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate) answer this question, then, marking it as "Offtopic" for now?

Comment: @TheLordofTime No.

Comment: My opinion is it's another "Go ask for support over there" making it an unwieldy on topic by force by recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

I suppose you want to know why, and it's a pretty easy answer: The team supporting the Nexus 7/Ubuntu Touch development are [actively monitoring the tag](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/5322/41). So, as they seem to require raring for ubuntu-touch they take the responsibility of the influx of questions about raring on ubuntu-touch. Furthermore, the whole "it's ubuntu+1" argument isn't that strong here. Per their instructions, it's only to ask questions not to report bugs, which is covered under [this question about ubuntu+1 questions](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate?lq=1)

Comment: [tag:mobile] has been made a synonym of [tag:ubuntu-touch], so are they monitoring that tag now?

Comment: Yes, they are automatically merged and so are the followers

Comment: Are you saying that we should not close questions about problems using Ubuntu+1 (even those not related to [tag:ubuntu-touch]), unless we're confident they should be filed as bug reports? Often it's very difficult to know if something is a bug, and practically speaking we close many Ubuntu+1 questions that we'd keep open if they were about a stable version of Ubuntu. And [these resources](http://askubuntu.com/q/18641) are not just for bugs. It seems to me that if we allow 13.04 tablet questions here, that really is an exception, not covered by any AU policy or consensus. How was this decided?

Comment: Unless it's a bug about Ubuntu-Touch, then the question will likely need to stay open. Other than that it follows the typical [questions about ubuntu+1](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate?lq=1) policy. To be honest there is very little special. Most all questions that aren't about bugs will fall under the bullet points listed in that policy. I'm not sure why people think this is anything special. The difference about most software and this is this is a "stewarded" tag, meaning upstream is actively monitoring it/using it for support.